# Move control freely inside AbsoluteLayout in .Net Maui

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I'm trying to make a layout that allow me to move controls inside it freely, I found a working solution but it has a very strange behavior, when I try to move the label, the movement is very laggy and sometimis it has an effect like it duplicate the label.

I implemented the movement with a PanGestureRecognizer adding labels inside an AbsoluteLayout programatically with a button event

This is the XAML, with the empty AbsoluteLayout and the button at the end to add de label

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Views.MoveControlsView"
             Title="MoveControlsView">
    <StackLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout
            x:Name="ParentLayout"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        
        <StackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="End">
            <Button
                x:Name="AddLabel"
                Text="Add label"
                Clicked="AddLabel_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the code behind, I generate a Label when the button is clicked and add to it the PanGestureRecognizer that I also suscribed it to the PanUpdated event.

```
public partial class MoveControlsView : ContentPage
{
    public MoveControlsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddLabel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var label = new Label() 
        { 
            Text = "This is a label", 
            BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGray, 
            Padding = 10
        }; 
        
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated;

        label.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);

        ParentLayout.Children.Add(label);
    }
    private void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = sender as Label;
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                label.TranslationX = e.TotalX;
                label.TranslationY = e.TotalY;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                label.TranslateTo(label.TranslationX, label.TranslationY);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the problems happen when you only have one label? What platform are you testing on? If Android or iOS, test on an actual device; emulator may be slow at updating UI, thus lag. If one label works fine on actual device, then you may need to detach the pan gesture when you are done moving it; perhaps having multiple pan gestures causes trouble. Just a guess.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've tried on my physical android device but has the same behavior, I don't think is because of multiple pan gestures, with only one label added it the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make changes to the code in **PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated** event handler. Try the following code:

```
    double tempx = 0;
    double tempy = 0;
    private void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = sender as Label;
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                {
                    tempx = label.TranslationX;
                    tempy = label.TranslationY;
                }

                break;

            case GestureStatus.Running:
                if (Device.RuntimePlatform  == Device.iOS)
                {
                    label.TranslationX = e.TotalX + tempx;
                    label.TranslationY = e.TotalY + tempy;
                }
                else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                    label.TranslationX += e.TotalX;
                    label.TranslationY += e.TotalY;
                }

                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                tempx = label.TranslationX;                  
                tempy = label.TranslationY;

                break;
        }
    }
```

For more information, you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout) and [Add a pan gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I tried your code, works perfectly fine and solves the problem that the label disappears sometimes, but unfortunetly has the same behavior like mine on the movement like a laggy one. Thanks for yur answer

Comment: Did you use a simulator or a device? Seems that it works well on my iphone simulator

Comment: That's because andriod and ios behave differently using pangesture. I have updated my answer. please have a try.

Comment: Now works perfectly, without laggy movements, I always use android simulator and physical device to test. thank you